# Separate WCF services for external vs internal clients OR single high performance service?

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, wcf, architecture

One of the architecture decision that i am going through is to build 2 services vs 1 for almost 90% same functionality. The key here is performance factor.

Logic for 2 services is:

1. External client service will be more high performance
2. Possibly if there are methods that only are required for external clients then this methods can be specific to this service.
3. There will be some common dll for core DAL, SAL functionality that will be utilized by both internal & external services. To ensure no code redundancy.

Logic for 1 service:

1. If the functionality  of external vs internal is not too different, adding a few methods should work.
2. Single high performance service, why should internal users suffer ? :)
3. With time, branching 2 services might add more overhead & risk of keeping some logic in sync as there will be 2 different teams involved. This can create discrepancies in similar appearing functions.

Is there a standard industry wide approach used for this classic argument?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend alot on how much common functionality and code there is between the 2 services. If it's 90% like you suggest it would seem silly to duplicate that code for another service. Also, from a maintenance perspective this would mean double the work is required for each change that is common to both external and internal.

It should be fairly simple to separate out functionality required for only external clients vs internal within 1 service (interfaces perhaps?). I would think it's more a matter of carefully designing 1 service at this point rather than trying to create and maintain 2.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your problem statement I would like to suggest use of one service.

if you use two services for the same functionality maintenance cost and integrity of your service might get compromise.Also if the problem is in the performance, better solution would be to use multiple service endpoints and load balancing to provide efficient use of the service.

In implementation you might have two different implementation to cater internal and external users ( use of interfaces and overriding functionalities) but all users points to the same service